# Angular Reactive form controls all report ng-valid and parent form reports as ng-valid but submit still disabled until clicking on a form control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Hoping I can get some help with debugging this application. The issue is that the submit button appears to be out of sync with the view model.

For example, I have a form with a select control that is a required field. The select options are built dynamically from an API service and so when the form loads the select already has a preselected option set and should be valid.

However, the submit button is disabled! the only way to get the submit button to enable is to simply click on the form and manually set a selected option (even if its the same option that was set when the form loads). This interaction causes the submit to enable.

Upon inspecting the HTML form onload, the form has ng-valid styles and no ng-invalid appears.

What would cause the button to be out of sync with the view and the reported ng-valid state of the control and parent form?

Comment: You can add some code examples you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to Reactive Forms. Will be easier to fix.

```
Template.html
    <form [formGroup]="formName">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>LABEL</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="controlName"/>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
    
    ...
       <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onSubmit()"
           [disabled]="fChildComponent?.invalid || f.invalid">SUBMIT</button>
```

component.ts

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;

get f(): FormGroup { return this.form; }
get fChildComponent(): FormGroup { return this.child.fchildForm }
```

Then you can can invalid state of child.
Or you can work on a custom `ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR and NG_VALIDATORS`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is an angular reactive form control.